# What can be deduced/extracted from this local hash extracted from Windows Machine?

Tags: hash, aes, passwords, password-hashing, sha-512

I'm new to cryptography. I've been experimenting with getting Windows hashes to see whether it's possible to reverse engineer. The following hash is what I got from my test laptop. What can you identify here and what is possible to do with this kind of hash. However, I'm not solely interested in extracting the password, but truly understanding which types of hashes are being used here.

I've extracted this hash by using a program called **Lazagne**.

Hash:

```
$$DPAPImk$2*1*S-1-5-21-3135680238-1618761808-2876590207-1001*aes256*sha512*8000*af87ccc856973aca8457d0a215ba71fd*288*e97a8bd1c9281cb7544ae53a3bd0e181dd9bc49f4bd6733d1226bce4b955a88a94b6938ca0e48bdcffdb59cec1ab98b17bef4d9ca87af21b6ea4ce52f781211912628813a9a50766afbedc4e3549412b9dab65ffd0db5458201887171b5053458afe04f20a30e2de3db60eba2f29291aac55f0e05f8f7c852f8434a907c87ded9d09e2832772a894a8a029ff1541a742
```

Comment: It lists in the text aes256 sha512

Comment: Ciphertext analysis and hash-preimage questions and alike are off-topic here. Can you make your question more clear that it's not about any of those?

Comment: Also, if you're interested in the inner working of MS Windows, why not consider [buying a book](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Windows+Internals)?

Comment: This seems to be a hash by the Microsoft Windows Data Protection API, AFAICT it is supported by common password-cracking tools. At the very last their source / commit messages / pull requests probably document how this hash works.

Comment: @SEJPM Yes, there are tools to extract like [this](https://www.passcape.com/windows_password_recovery_dpapi_master_key). I looked for the official format, but couldn't find it.